# Defining Mongoose Relationship to Schema of existing legacy MongoDB schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm in the process of re-writing a production Ruby application in NodeJs; our Ruby schema defined the MongoDB object like the example below.

A Company has many Users, a User belongs to many Companies

```
// User
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b3a8344f7e49c50b882a4a3"),
  "name" : "Example User",
  "company_ids" : [ 
    ObjectId("5b3a8344f7e49c50b882a47e"), 
    ObjectId("5b3a8344f7e49c50b882a47f"), 
    ObjectId("5bdb97bff7e49c1e0a5964f3")
  ],
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-04-05T23:07:27.001Z"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2018-07-02T19:55:49.422Z")
}

// Company
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b3a8344f7e49c50b882a47e"),
  "name" : "Example Company",
  "number" : 1, 
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-04-05T23:07:27.001Z"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2018-07-02T19:55:49.422Z")
}
```

So far I have been trying to define my relationship between the models in the following way, but I have not been successful, I presume mongoose is trying to look for `companyIds` and it isn't finding it on the database, but I have no idea how to manually specify what field to map.

```
// ./src/models/User.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  companies: [{ 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Company', 
    companyIds: 'company_ids' // <- not working
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
})
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

-

```
// ./src/models/Company.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
})

mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look in [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases), your best option is `aliases`, you could write your Schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "name": String,
});
var Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);

var compA = Company({ name: 'a'});
var compB = Company({ name: 'b'});
var compC = Company({ name: 'c'});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "company_ids": {
    type: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Company',
    }], 
    alias: 'companies'
  }
})
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var user = new User({ companies: [compA, compB, compC]});
console.log(user)
console.log(user.companies);
```

When you log the object, you obtain `{ company_ids: [compA, compB, compC]}`, but besides that, you may use the "companies" field, like this:

```
var user = new User({ companies: [compA, compB, compC]});
console.log(user) // { company_ids: [compA, compB, compC] }
console.log(user.companies); // [compA, compB, compC]
user.companies = [compA, compB]
console.log(user.companies); // [compA, compB]
```

Comment: this only returns the ID though of the company -- not the company object itself unfortunately